# Entering values in a 2-D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

```
for i in range(limit_1):
    for j in range(limit_2):
        a[i][j]=np.sqrt(np.absolute(b[i])**2+np.absolute(c[j])**2)
```

Is there an alternative way to perform this task, using perhaps a numpy function?

Comment: can you show how should look the expected array?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : the array should be 2x2 array with elements a[i][j] given by the expression in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your **original** code:

```
limit_1 = 4
limit_2 = 3

import numpy as np
a = np.zeros([limit_1, limit_2])
b = np.array([1, -6, 7, 3])
c = np.array([3, 2, -1])

print("Original:")
for i in range(limit_1):
    for j in range(limit_2):
        a[i][j]=np.sqrt(np.absolute(b[i])**2+np.absolute(c[j])**2)

print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
Original:
[[ 3.16227766  2.23606798  1.41421356]
 [ 6.70820393  6.32455532  6.08276253]
 [ 7.61577311  7.28010989  7.07106781]
 [ 4.24264069  3.60555128  3.16227766]]
```

And the **shortened version**:

```
print("Improved:")
a = np.sqrt(
        np.tile(np.array([b]).transpose(), (1, limit_2)) ** 2 +\
        np.tile(np.array(c).transpose(), (limit_1, 1)) ** 2)

print(a)
```

Outputs:

```
Improved:
[[ 3.16227766  2.23606798  1.41421356]
 [ 6.70820393  6.32455532  6.08276253]
 [ 7.61577311  7.28010989  7.07106781]
 [ 4.24264069  3.60555128  3.16227766]]
```

---

## Explanation

First we stretch the vector column `b` to a matrix (and then take it's 2nd power):

```
>>> np.tile(np.array([b]).transpose(), (1, limit_2))
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [-6, -6, -6],
       [ 7,  7,  7],
       [ 3,  3,  3]])

>>> np.tile(np.array([b]).transpose(), (1, limit_2)) ** 2
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [36, 36, 36],
       [49, 49, 49],
       [ 9,  9,  9]])
```

Then we do the same for the row column `c`:

```
>>> np.tile(np.array(c).transpose(), (limit_1, 1))
array([[ 3,  2, -1],
       [ 3,  2, -1],
       [ 3,  2, -1],
       [ 3,  2, -1]])
>>> np.tile(np.array(c).transpose(), (limit_1, 1)) ** 2
array([[9, 4, 1],
       [9, 4, 1],
       [9, 4, 1],
       [9, 4, 1]])
```

We then sum them together and calculate the root.

---

P.S. 1 - I used only the squared power instead of the absolute value, but if you still need the absolute value you can use it the same way.

P.S. 2 - Notice that the calculation can be done more efficient, i.e calculate the power before we tile the arrays, but this way is more clearer for this post)

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no point of squaring the absolute value as `n**2` and `abs(n)**2` are exactly the same.

Either way, using list comprehension:

```
temp = [math.sqrt(numpy.absolute(x)**2 + numpy.absolute(y)**2) for x in b for y in c]
a = [temp[x:x+limit_2] for x in range(0, len(temp), limit_2)]
```

Comment: The elements of the array in my case can also be complex

Comment: @PrishChakraborty Either way, this solution should work

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by extending `b` from `1D` to `2D` by introducing a new singleton axis as the second axis with [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then perform operations  against `c`. This would simplify things there and also achieved a vectorized method, like so -

```
np.sqrt(np.abs(b[:,None])**2 + np.abs(c)**2)
```

As also talked about in the other answers that since squaring would inherently produce `non-negative` numbers, so we can just skip the `absolute` operation, to give us -

```
np.sqrt(b[:,None]**2 + c**2)
```